# Check sub string character are in sequence of main string

Tags: java, algorithm

Lets say you have word "google" and you are given other strings "glo" should return false as l is after o so characters are not in sequence. where as if given string "goe" should return true, as g->o->e are in sequence.

Comment: You don't have a question in your question! But assuming it was 'how do I do that'...what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a greedy algorithm:

- Start locate the first letter from the sequence in the word; record its index `ind0`
- Starting at `ind0`, look for the second letter from the sequence; record its index `ind1`
- Starting at `ind1`, look for the third letter from the sequence; record its index `ind2`
- Continue with this process until you either (a) run out of letters in the sequence, or (b) cannot locate the next letter in the word
- If you ran out of letters in the sequence, return `true`
- Otherwise, return `false`.

This algorithm is linear in the number of letters in the word. If a solution exists, this algorithm will discover it. Intuitively, it will never advance `ind...` past the index of the matching letter; matching an earlier letter does not prevent us from matching the following letter, if a match exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have just one query that you want to answer, [dasblinkenlight's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24770794/862351) is as good as it can get. Now, if you have many such queries to perform on the same base string, say B,(= "google", in your example) and you have `O(|S|*N)` memory, where `S` is the alphabet you are dealing with and `N = len(B)` is the size of the base string, you can do this:

1. In `O(|S|*N)` time, compute `NEXT(i, a) = Smallest j such that j>i and B[j]=a`. If there is no such `j`, `NEXT(i,a) = inf`. Also, define `NEXT(-1, a)` to be the first occurence of `a`.
2. Given a query string, Q, check that find `NEXT(-1, Q[0])`, NEXT(NEXT(-1, Q[0]), Q[1])... and ensure they are all finite.

This way, you need `O(|S|*N)` preprocessing time, while every query will be `O(|Q|)` time.